# Failed to initialize PeerConnectionFactory

Tags: iphone, ios, xmpp, webrtc, libjingle

I am using libJingle for webRtc with iOS client, but it is throwing runtime Error

```
Failed to initialize PeerConnectionFactory
```

This happens when session gets created and initial video stream successfully received. After that, when subscription process with webRtc has to begin, this error shows up.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

The webrtc code for iOS on Google is not complete.  It is likely throwing an error due to the many stubbed out objective-c callbacks.  I spent a few months on this and put together this working webrtc iOS app on github.

https://github.com/gandg/webrtc-ios

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! I really appreciate your efforts on this.